# How to load a particular section in Sidebar of a google Addon, when a modal dialogue is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to create a add on in google docs. A part of the add on allows the user to give some input which i get in a modal dialogue box. When the user saves the changes i should close the dialogue box and update a section in the sidebar based on the users input.

I tried to save the details in PropertiesService and then load the Sidebar with those details

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function ()
{ 
 google.script.host.close();
}).sidebar_UI();

function sidebar_UI() 
{
  var sidebar_UI = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sidebar_UI").evaluate();
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_UI);
}
```

I am eager to know if there is any way not to load the whole sidebar but a particular section, after the users details are stored in PropertiesService.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some Javascript in your HTML files that will query the server code for whatever information you want to display.

Basically, you are saving properties in your modal window and then retrieving that data from the sidebar. I don't think there is a cleaner way to pass data from the modal dialog into the sidebar.

Here is an example:

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Open Sidebar', 'openSidebar')
    .addToUi();

}

function onInstall() {
  onOpen();
}

function openSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')
    .evaluate();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Modal')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Modal');
}

function saveName(name) {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('STUDENT_NAME', name);
}

function getName() {
  return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('STUDENT_NAME');
}
```

Modal.html

```
<form onsubmit="submitName(event)">
  <input type="text" name="studentName" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function submitName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var studentName = e.target.studentName.value;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
      .saveName(studentName);
  }
</script>
```

Sidebar.html

```
<section>

  <button onclick="showDialog()">Open Modal</button>
  <button onclick="getName()">Update Name</button>

  <h1>Name:</h1>
  <div id="response">
    <!-- the thing you are changing in the modal goes here -->
  </div>
</section>


<script>
function showDialog() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(getName)
    .showDialog();
}

function getName() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = res;
    })
    .getName();
}

</script>
```

Comment: if i use "DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_UI.evaluate());", anyway am loading the whole sidebar UI right, i want to load a particular section. @jordan

Comment: Well, you will need to setup your sidebar with the templated HTML so that it only displays the sections that you want.

Comment: And as I think about it, you could even just create several different HTML files and open the one that you need based on the user input.

Comment: I have a sidebar, from which I open a modal dialogue .Once the user enters details and hit the save button, the modal dialogue is closed and the user details are stored. Now i don't want to reload the whole sidebar, but to reload a particular section only in the old sidebar with the saved details from modal dialogue box@jordan

Comment: To update the sidebar without a reload, you will just have to make another google.script.run.getSectionDetails() call in the withSuccessHandler of the modal window.

Comment: sorry @joradn still now i cant get you. can u help with some sample code?